# Adding integers which are in strings in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, string, floating-point, integer, addition

For example I have "$100" and "$50" in two strings, I want to add them to get an output "$150".
I know the general method(converting them into integers and adding them), but i am searching for a shorter method which does not call many functions

Comment: The *general method* is to hold your data using a data type that makes them easy to manipulate, in this case integers, and to convert them to strings during presentation.  Don't hold them using strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse the string into a NSNumber, Sum them and then convert back to String :

```
NSString *strNum1 = "$100";
NSString *strNum2 = "$150";

NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSNumber * myFirstNumber = [f numberFromString:strNum1];
NSNumber * mySecNumber = [f numberFromString:strNum2];

NSNumber *sum = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([myFirstNumber floatValue] + [mySecNumber floatValue])];
NSString * strSum = [f stringFromNumber:sum];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
float result = [[fiftyBucks substringFromIndex:1] floatValue] + [[hundredBucks substringFromIndex:1] floatValue];
```

or use NSScanner, but it will be little longer, but more reliably/safely:

```
float fifty, hundred, result;
[[NSScaner scannerWithString: fiftyBucks] scanFloat: &fifty];
[[NSScaner scannerWithString: hundredBucks] scanFloat: &hundred];
result = fifty + hundred;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you better store the price at CGfloat instead.

showing a string "$100" is a front-end task and calculating the sum of the prices are back end task. These two should be seperated.

If you store the price as a CGFloat, you can simply do the maths.
And when you wanna show that string, juz implement a method.

```
- (NSString *)priceLabel:(CGFloat) _price {
     return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"$.1f", _price];
}
```

Besides, don't be afraid of making a Front-end Helper model when you code. I put all this kind of minor  method in this model as a class method. Wherever you need reuse this method, you can simply import the model.

Comment: **CGFloat** is core graphics type, so it's wrong to use it instead of usual **float**